# How can I use my fingerprint reader?

Tags: 10.10, fingerprint-reader

I have an HP dv4 2080br with a fingerprint reader that works fine on Windows 7. `lsusb` lists it as

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 138a:0005 DigitalPersona
```

How can I use it on Ubuntu 10.10?

Answer (score 3):

There is a packaged called fprint available in this [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/fprint) However, it does not appear that your device is listed as "Supported". There is a bug [Bug #285089](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/285089) Which details issues with a similar USB device id though I don't believe it is related nor confirmation that this device does not work with the fprint package.

Answer (score 1):

try this! searched for around 5 months trying to get mine to install..... you WILL find one of the three will work. https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint  as far as which one will work... well thats trial and error

Answer (score 0):

Assumed that you are using Ubuntu 12.10.

Install the `libpam-fprintd` and `printd` packages from universe.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libpam-fprintd fprintd
```

You should see the following.

```
$ grep fprint /etc/pam.d/common-auth 
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_fprintd.so
```

Enroll your fingerprint.

```
$ fprintd-enroll
```

For additional security you may want to use only password to log in to the desktop. Then do the following.

```
$ sudo cp /etc/pam.d/common-auth /etc/pam.d/common-auth-nofinger
$ sudo vi /etc/pam.d/common-auth-nofinger
```

Edit `/etc/pam.d/common-auth-nofinger`. Remove the line

```
auth    [success=3 default=ignore] pam_fprintd.so
```

and save and quit.

```
$ sudo vi /etc/pam.d/lightdm
```

Edit `/etc/pam.d/lightdm` (or /etc/pam.d/gdm, if that's what you're using) so that it "@includes" `/etc/pam.d/common-auth-nofinger` rather than `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`.