# How to use fingerprint authentication on a HP DV6-3049TX?

Tags: hardware, fingerprint-reader, hp-pavilion, peripherals

How can I use the fingerprint reader on my HP DV6-3049TX?

I've tried it with some software (please edit so we know what you've tried) but it just says "No device".

Comment: Please append the post with the output of `lspci` and `lsusb` so we can see what the fingerprint reader we're dealing with here is.

Comment: What is the make of the fingerprint reader (eg. 'Validity')? What software is used to make it work on Windows (eg. 'Digital Persona')?

Answer (score 1):

There's a similar question asked here:

[How can I use my fingerprint reader?](https://askubuntu.com/q/15029/6211)

This comment: [FPrint](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15029/how-can-i-use-my-fingerprint-reader/15040#15040) -  points out a software that could help you, it has a list of supported devices, but aparently your laptop is not in the list. Nonetheless I would give it a try

Answer (score 0):

try this:   http://www.ubuntu-unleashed.com/2008/04/get-your-fingerprint-reader-to-work-in.html