# How do I use my fingerprint reader?

Tags: software-recommendation, fingerprint-reader

I have a HP dv6190 that originally ran windows seven which the fingerprint reader worked fine with. Does anyone know any software I can download to use it with. Also if you could tell me the step by step process as I'm still new to Linux as a whole. Right now I'm running Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: What further information do you need that is not contained in this AU Question? http://askubuntu.com/questions/15029/how-can-i-use-my-fingerprint-reader

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyways or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reasons why you want it open. Regards